# SQL bypass REPLACE by CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace, case, sql-server-2014

I have data where some records contain blank rows (=no space, no NULL). E.g.:

```
LOCALE
en-es
en-uk

uk-uk
```

When I want to select that blank row, it's easy with:

```
SELECT LOCALE
FROM ABC
WHERE LOCALE = ''
```

But when I try to replace it as follows, it does not work, the result is still blank row:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LOCALE,'','WHY') AS 'LOCALE'
FROM ABC
WHERE LOCALE = ''
```

But if I bypass this with `CASE` statement, it works:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN LOCALE LIKE '' THEN 'WHY'
       ELSE LOCALE
       END AS 'LOCALE'
FROM ABC
WHERE LOCALE = ''
```

What is the problem here? Why does `REPLACE` function not work?

Comment: You cannot replace an empty string.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I think the OP already got that part, the question is why it can't be done...

Comment: try this SELECT REPLACE(' ',' ','WHY') AS 'LOCALE'  is space is there then you can replace it . empty sting you cannot

Comment: [`REPLACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) is "find every occurrence of the second string within the first string and replace it with this third string" not "compare the first and second strings and, if they are equal, return the third string, otherwise return the first string"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever While true, if the second argument is equal to the first, the return value will be the third argument (as I'm sure you know very well). In this case, the question is **Why can't I use replace for an empty string?**, which I personally believe the answer is **because. Go ask Microsoft.** :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - replacing empty strings is troublesome because there can be so many of them. How many empty strings appear between the characters `A` and `B` in the string `AB`? (The answer can be 0, 1, 99 or any other positive number you care to think of)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good point. I think this is the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever great point. please post it as an answer in future somebody can refer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is obvious that `''` means blank (Not null) and it exists between two consecutive letters also. (As it is blank)

So Sql can not go on replacing *that* blank in between every letter with the string you want. That's why you can not replace `''`

Check this query

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(LOCALE, ''),'WHY') AS [LOCALE]
FROM ABC
WHERE LOCALE = ''
```

Comment: It's not *impossible*, it's just something that sql server developers did not allow...

Comment: I've voted your answer up since you are the only one that understood the question at the moment :-)

Comment: just verify the answer that you are posted because when i run that it only display W rather than 'WHY'

Comment: Is your column has length of `1` in table `ABC` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your replace function not replace blank space.
Try to this

```
SELECT REPLACE(isnull(ITEM,''),' ','WHY') AS 'LOCALE'
FROM Table1
WHERE ITEM = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only an alternative method 
try the below method

```
select COALESCE(NULLIF('',''), 'WHY' AS 'LOCALE'
FROM ABC
WHERE LOCALE = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for you to use **[NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)** to convert empty string to `NULL`, after It to use **[COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)** (*ANSI standard*) to replace `NULL` to any value you want, in following:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(LOCALE, ''),'WHY') AS 'LOCALE' 
FROM ABC 
WHERE LOCALE = ''
```